# Dell M14x Alienware cannot play 1999 Street war

Tags: technical-issues, backwards-compatibility, street-wars

I've installed the old school 'Street Wars/Mob Rule' game to my laptop. When I run the game, suddenly I can only hear the sound but no display. When I click Alt+Tab button to change a window, the game display appears for a while. It also happen with 'Neighbors from Hell' game. Is it because of screen resolution? My display is 1366 x 768 max and 800 x 600 min. Both games require only 640x480 graphic display.

Comment: What OS are you using? I'd assume these games expect/want something in the NT4 family.

Comment: i am using window 7. is there any problem with the OS?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is available on GOG.com ([Mob Rule](http://www.gog.com/game/mob_rule)) would indicate that it will work under DOSBox (since that's what GOG use). So either get hold of DOSBox and use that, or spring for a small amount of cash and get the GOG version.

Comment: So how does DOSbox work for the game? If I install the DOSbox, then should I re-install the game? Sorry, I really don't know the purpose and how to use it.